# Python: GUI based "reverse entry" using recursion failing

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion

I am trying to make a Python program that asks the user for a number then reverses it using recursion. My attempt is below, but my code gives me TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'Entry' and 'int' - any ideas?

```
from tkinter import * 

def reverseInteger(n, r):
    if n==0:
        return r
    else:
        return reverseInteger(n//10, r*10 + n%10)

window = Tk() 
window.title("Reverse Integer")

frame1 = Frame(window) 
frame1.pack()

number = StringVar()
numEntry = Entry(frame1, textvariable=number) 
btGetName = Button(frame1, text = "Calculate", command = reverseInteger(numEntry, 0)) 
label3 = Label(frame1)

numEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
btGetName.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
label3.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function is perfectly fine but there are several other
problems in your code.

The main one is that the `command` parameter of `Button` must be the
function that will be called when the user presses on the buttton.  In
your code, `command` is set to the return value of `reverseInteger`
which is an int.  So there is a problem here.

Also it seems to me that you want to put the result of your
calculation in `label3` so your `StringVar` should be attached to it
and not to `numEntry`.

So here is a version that seems ok to me:

```py
from tkinter import *

def reverseInteger(n, r):
    if n==0:
        return r
    else:
        return reverseInteger(n//10, r*10 + n%10)

def reverse():  # called when the user click on the button
    value = reverseInteger(int(numEntry.get()), 0)
    number.set(value)  # change the text of the label

window = Tk() 
window.title("Reverse Integer")

frame1 = Frame(window) 
frame1.pack()

number = StringVar()
numEntry = Entry(frame1) 
btGetName = Button(frame1, text = "Calculate", command = reverse) 
label3 = Label(frame1, textvariable=number)

numEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
btGetName.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
label3.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```